# Can we send/display badge count for silent iOS notifications?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, push, badge

I want to handle badge count increment in iOS application. On the basis of research I did so far I understand that app can read/update badge programmatically when it is in foreground. Also, ‘application:didReceiveRemoteNotification’  is called only when application is in foreground state.

However, I want to be able to increase badge even when my app is in background state. I came across the notification callback method below which gets invoked even during the background state -
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler

It is introduced in iOS 7. However I noticed that even this newly introduced callback is not invoking in background state. Then after doing little more research I realised that this method calls only in case of Silent iOS notifications. So now my question is, is it possible to show badge count for silent notifications, can I receive badge count in payload ? I was just thinking of implementing the badge count calculation by leveraging the background support available for silent notifications.

Any suggestions/guidance/help is extremely invaluable for us at this moment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can put badge count in payload. In this case, the server side should handle the number of badge count. For example:

`{
    "aps" : {
        "badge" : 5,
    },
}`

If your app is running foreground and to increase/decrease the badge count sent by server, this following example would help.

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo  {
    NSLog(@"remote notification: %@",[userInfo description]);

    if (userInfo) {
        NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);

        if ([userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]) { 
            if([[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"badgecount"]) {
                [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey: @"badgecount"] intValue];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If we are being consistent with the payload, shouldn't the key be `"badge"` instead of `"badgecount"`?